# Show that $4\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal in $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Show that $4\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal in $2\mathbb{Z}$.

We will use the fact that $4\mathbb{Z}$ maximal $\iff 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is a field.
$$2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} = \{k + 4\mathbb{Z} : k \in 2\mathbb{Z}\}$$
We are going to determine the number of elements in this set. Let $k\in 2\mathbb{Z}$.
$$k \equiv 0 \mod4 \implies k+4\mathbb{Z} = 0 + 4\mathbb{Z}$$
$$k \equiv 1 \mod4 \implies 4|(k-1) \implies k = 4r+1 \implies 2\not|k$$
$$k \equiv 2\mod 4 \implies 2+4\mathbb{Z} \in 2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$$
$$k \equiv 3 \mod4 \implies 4|(k-3) \implies k = 4r+3 \implies 2\not|k$$
So the set has $2$ elements. This means it is a field since $0 +4\mathbb{Z}$ is the zero, and $2+4\mathbb{Z}$ is the one. i.e every non-zero element is invertible. Infact we have $$2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \cong\mathbb{Z}_{2}$$

There are most likely an easier way to show the isomorphism, but I can't think of it.

Comment: I've being trying to use the 3rd isomorphism theorem, but I think I'm blind, mind showing me explicitly?

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634800/is-2-mathbbz-4-mathbbz-not-a-field?rq=1), as $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a field (your $I$ maximal $\iff$ $R/I$ a field is for _unital_ commutative rings).

Comment: Are you viewing $2\Bbb{Z}$ and $4\Bbb{Z}$ as abelian groups under addition or rngs or what?

Comment: @RobArthan Rings

Comment: But then these are rings *without 1* (which are often called rngs) and the quotient $2\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ is *not* a field. However $4\Bbb{Z}$ is a maximal proper subrng of $2\Bbb{Z}$ (by considering the additive structure alone).

Comment: Yea, I see now, I didn't consider that the ring had to be unital, as Mark mentioned. Can I say let $j\in 2\mathbb{Z}\setminus 4\mathbb{Z}$. Then $(2,j) = (gcd(2,j)) = (2) = 2\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exists an ideal $A$ in $2 \mathbb Z$ such that $4\mathbb Z \subseteq A \subseteq 2\mathbb Z.$ Since, $I$ is an ideal of $2 \mathbb Z,$ therefore, it must be of the form $2m \mathbb Z$ for some $m \in \mathbb Z.$

So, we have $2\cdot 2 \mathbb Z \subseteq 2m \mathbb Z\subseteq 2 \mathbb Z.$ So, $I$ must either be $4\mathbb Z$ or $2\mathbb Z.$ Hence, $4 \mathbb Z$ is maximal.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that any subgroup of $2\Bbb{Z}$ has to be of the form $2n\Bbb{Z}$ for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$, implies that $4\Bbb{Z}$ is maximal in $2\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hehe. Yes, it should not have been there. :)

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}\subset 2m\mathbb{Z} \subset 2\mathbb{Z} \implies m|2$ or $ m|1$ but $m\neq 1$. And your fact should follow from the correspondance theorem right?

Comment: @pureundersgrad Since any set of positive integers should have a minimal element. Let the minimal element of a subgroup of $2\Bbb{Z}$ be $n$, then the subgroup should be $n\Bbb{Z}$, now as $n\in2\Bbb{Z}$, $|n|=2k$, for some $k\in\Bbb{N}$, hence the subgroup is $2k\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: Does that results hold for rings?

Comment: A ring is a group under addition